# JAVA, cuenta regresiva y viceversa al mismo tiempo en bucles

Tags: java, netbeans

Realiza un programa que muestre en pantalla, dado un número N, el siguiente resultado:

Para N = 7 sería

```
1 7
2 6
3 5
4 4
5 3
6 4
7 1
```

Estoy intentando hacer dos bucles while que se ejecuten al mismo tiempo pero no sé como enlazarlos para que se muestre por pantalla el proceso al mismo tiempo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
         Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println("Introduce N:");
 
        int numero = entrada.nextInt();
        
        
         while (i <= numero) {
            System.out.println(i);
            i+=1;
            
            if (i <= 1) {
            
            while (i >= numero) {
            System.out.println("N" +i);
            i--;
            
         }
            
         }
```

Comment: Realmente no necesitas calcular los dos números. Tienes el número mayor (que suponemos es `numeroMax`) y siempre comienzas de 1, sería ir aumentando `i` y al "pintar en consola" puedes mostrar `i` y `numeroMax - (i-1)`. Ahí veríás `i` subiendo y el otro valor descendiendo comenzando por `numeroMax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas dos ciclos, únicamente uno.
Sabes cual es tu entrada, y puedes guardarla en una variable auxiliar para modificarla sin perder el valor original hasta el que debes iterar.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int entrada = 7;

        int inicio = 1;
        int entradaAux = entrada;

        while(inicio <= entrada && entradaAux >= 1) {
            System.out.println(inicio + " " + entradaAux);
            inicio++;
            entradaAux--;
        }
    }
}
```